# ionic 2 push notification not working in my custom page?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

In my ionic 2 app, I have 2 pages index.html (default loading page) and channel.html (a general page not present in app/pages). 
I receive push  notification when I'm in index.html but I will not receive when I'm in channel.html.
Can anyone please suggest me what should I do so that I can get the push notification on both the pages. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show some code where you are receiving notifications ?

Comment: var push = Push.init({
        android: {
          senderID: "XXXXXXXXX"
        },
        ios: {
          alert: "true",
          badge: true,
          sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {}
      });
      push.on('registration', (data) => {
        console.log(data.registrationId);
        alert(data.registrationId.toString());
      });

       push.on('notification', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
          alert("Hi, Am a push notification");
      });

Comment: I use it in /src/app/app.component.ts file. I can receive push notification with this when I'm in index.html but not when I'm switch to channel.html on some button click.

Comment: I think you have to do the reverse. when you receive the notification of a relevant page, push the page with data as parameter.

Comment: for example here:https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59#.b0sk4r2c0

Comment: or theoretically,you could set the push variable after initialization in a separate provider.though havent tried it

Comment: I have tried this. This will help in receiving notification only when you have single page app. Just with different constraints like when app is in background, when app is closed etc. But it will not help to receive notification in the custom page... If I'm wrong at understanding it please do suggest the right way ..

Comment: you could receive in app.component.ts and push/open the custom page..

Comment: Could you please suggest how to do that custom page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ionic 2, it's not a good practice to create a custom loading page it is always good to have index.html as default loading page. The reasons are

- Index.html acts as the container for all pages that are present in
  src/pages.
- As index.html acts as container for all pages any notification will
  work only in those pages. If you navigate to any other page present
  in  src/custom_page or to some external URL it is not treated as
  ionic page so push will not work.
- During ionic build the index.html is built and transferred from
  src/index.html to www/index.html it will not happen with any of the
  custom page.
- If you are bound by your requirement of custom page I suggest take
  your time and modify the existing code so you can cope-up with
  index.html as default loading page, because custom loading will trouble
  your projects in future.